# Problem with google chrome devtools Elements/Properties

Tags: google-chrome, devtools

Hi I have a problem with google chrome devtools: Elements/Properties.
When i selected an element in properties window it showed element + selectors. Now it shows this weird code. I also tried to restart all the settings, but the problem doesn't go away.

Comment: Would you include the 'weird code' you received? It may be helpful in determining the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/f90Kdop.png Hi, this is the screenshot for my problem